# how to give password protection in jspdf package?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using JSPDF for creating a PDF file but I cant give password protection on it. how to create password protected pdf with jspdf package in react?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Current have no way set password with jspdf. Use [node-qpdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qpdf) package to make your pdf be protected.

```
var qpdf = require('node-qpdf');

var options = {
    keyLength: 128,
    password: 'YOUR_PASSWORD_TO_ENCRYPT'
}

qpdf.encrypt(localFilePath, options);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found it is there in current version.                                                                                                 const doc = new jsPDF({
              encryption: {
                userPassword: Anything,
                userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
              }
            });

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release of jspdf >= 2.2.0, they have added encryption mechanism, to password protect the pdf file.
But note that

`jsPDF supports encryption of PDF just uses RC4 40-bit which is kown to be weak and is NOT state of the art.`

On example of usage is:

```
var doc = new jsPDF({
  encryption: {
    userPassword: "user",
    ownerPassword: "owner",
    userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
  }
});
```